# How do you force a first quotation mark vs a last quotation mark?

Tags: php, html

Strange question. My script is putting an end quotation mark at the beginning of the title instead of a beginning quotation mark.

Not sure I'm using the right terminology, but the keyboard only has one quotation mark key and context determines whether it's the type that goes before the quote or the type that goes after it.

Here's the code that's being used:

```
<h2>"<?PHP echo purify($post['title']);?>"</h2>
```

I also tried this:

```
<h2><?PHP echo '"' . purify($post['title']) . '"';?></h2>
```

I'm feeling like a big dunce here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you talking about typographic quotes? http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html

Comment: Quote marks are annoying like that, the only program I've found to consistently use the correct ones is MS Word!!! Keyboard entered quotes are non-aligned " rather than '66' or '99' quotes (doubles)

Comment: "Smart" quotes are the bane of my existence. Nothing breaks code like copy/pasting from something that uses them, or trying to parse text that contains them. If you're *really* committed to this manner of shenanigan use the HTML entities from the answers below, but consider doing the world a favor and *not* doing that at all. `:I`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to ensure the output is to use html entities.

```
&ldquo; TITLE &rdquo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not only:

```
<h2>&ldquo;<?=purify($post['title']);?>&ldquo;</h2>
```